# How to trigger f11 effect only after 5 seconds of pressing key using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to trigger f11 effect only after 5 seconds of pressing key using javascript or jquery?

Comment: What's the oldest browser you need to support?

Comment: The latest version of google chrome 58.0.3029.81

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the fullscreen API is only allowed if its use immediately follows a user action (like pressing a button). I've tested and a 1-second delay is the highest that seems to work reliably. Anything longer may be denied by the browser for not originating from a user action.

Here's the code for the 1-second delay if you find it useful:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.onkeydown = function() {
    if(event.keyCode === 122) {
        event.preventDefault();
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen();
        }, 1000);
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it will be enough for me.

Comment: @romaincapocasale Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted so other users know that the question's been answered.